# Узнать что за проект в параметрах/настройках

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как можно узнать что за проект создан. Информацию что это за проект.

Я перешла в параметры, вижу там список тип

[image: введите сюда описание изображения],

тип библиотек много

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как узнать что именно за приложение, где смотреть ?

Comment: Возможно я ошибаюсь, но вроде как от типа проекта зависит начальная конфигурация проекта, т. е. выбирается заготовка, а следовательно типов проектов в разы меньше, чем указывается здесь. Поэтому хранить тип проекта нет смысла, ведь любой проект (даже библиотеку классов) можно легко переконфигурировать в другой проект (библиотека классов WPF) просто подключив нужные библиотеки

Comment: Все библиотеки классов - это один тип, разница лишь в заранее заготовленных данных и настройках этого проекта, которые за вас любезно делает студия. Например в WPF библиотеке `TargetFramework` будет сразу установлен на `net7.0-windows` (нацелен на Windows), также будет добавлен `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>`, что подключит необходимые для WPF компоненты в проект. Для WPF (контрол) будет дополнительно еще созданы стартовые файлы (шаблон). Ну а для Razor будет добавлен пакет `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web` и созданы стартовые файлы и папки. Как видите, все одно, разница лишь в содержимом.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` добавлен где ? в каком файле, по какой ссылке

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuznL.png в проекте, я могу предположить по иконке, что это веб. так же название подсказывает, что возможно это блазор, но блазор есть сервер и васм...и потом просто догадки, а где посмотреть что это.

Comment: `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` - это все настройки проекта, то есть файл `csproj`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ 
 `<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>` 
настройки моего csproj мало мне о чем говорят

Comment: TargetFramework можно выбрать при создании 7 или 6. это понятно. А где что то типа UseBlazor...true, как узнать какой пакет создали

Comment: Смотрите, C# проекты можно по сути разделить на 2 части - Консольные и UI проекты, вот если проект консольный, то ему не нужны всякие `Use...` настройки, ибо это просто набор классов, которые что-то выполняют. С UI проектами чуть сложнее, ибо для того, чтобы написать простой компонент для UI, нужны SDK библиотеки этого UI, которые и добавляются при помощи настроек `Use...`. Я знаю 3 типа проекта с `Use` - WPF (`UseWPF`), WinForms (`UseWindowsForms`), и MAUI (`UseMaui`), остальные я не смотрел, но в теории также есть `UseUWP`, и мб в Xamarin также что-то есть (не уверен).

Comment: В любом случае, эти все проекты - это простая библиотека классов, просто с доп. настройками, которые можно переопределить в любой момент, и также подключить к любому типу проекта. Так что, ваш вопрос "что за тип проекта" тут не совсем уместен, ибо ответ будет "библиотека классов", всегда)